# STL Map - Displaying what is pointed to by find() function

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, iostream

For testing purposes, I'm running the following code through a `for` loop. Only the first three keys actually exist, and **"Record found"** is displayed as expected, along with the key, retrieved from `findVertex->first`.

- My question is, how would I be able to access the second value being pointed to?

`findVertex->second`seems obvious, but does not work, as the second value is an object I created, the declaration of which is given below the code, if it would be of any use.

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
     map<int, vector<Vertex> >::const_iterator findVertex = vertexMap.find(i);

     if(findVertex != vertexMap.end())
      {
          cout<<"\nRecord found: ";
          cout<<findVertex->first;
          cout<<findVertex->second; //does not work
      }
     else
         cout<<"\nRecord not found";
}
```

**Class code:**

```
class Vertex
{
    private:
        int currentIndex;
        double xPoint, yPoint, zPoint;
        vector<double> attributes;

    public:
        friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Vertex &);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Vertex &);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide an operator: `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const std::vector<Vertex>&)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you may not use `const_iterator`

```
map<int, vector<Vertex> >::const_iterator findVertex = vertexMap.find(i);
```

to display Vertex because you declared `operator <<` with second parameter as a non-const reference

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Vertex &); 
                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

You should declare it like

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Vertex &);
                                     ^^^^^
```

Otherwise change the above statement to the following

```
map<int, vector<Vertex> >::iterator findVertex = vertexMap.find(i);
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

And change this statement

```
cout<<findVertex->second; //does not work
```

to the following code snippet

```
for ( Vertex &v : findVertex->second ) cout << v << endl;
```

If you will modify the operator specyfying qualifier const for the second parameter then you can write

```
map<int, vector<Vertex> >::const_iterator findVertex = vertexMap.find(i);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//...

for ( const Vertex &v : findVertex->second ) cout << v << endl;
      ^^^^^
```

Or instead of the range based for statement you can use an ordinary loop as for example

```
for ( std::vector<Vertex>::size_type i = 0; i < findVertex->second.size(); i++ )
{
    std::cout << findVertex->second[i] << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
for ( std::vector<Vertex>::iterator it = findVertex->second.begin(); 
      it != findVertex->second.end(); 
      ++it )
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `map` is of the type

```
map<int, vector<Vertex>>
```

This means `first` is an `int`, and `second` is `vector<Vertex>`.

While you have defined `operator<<` for `Vertex`, there is no such function for `vector<Vertex>`. You'd have iterate through your `vector`, if you have access to C++11 you can use something like

```
 if(findVertex != vertexMap.end())
 {
     cout << "\nRecord found: ";
     cout << findVertex->first << '\n';
     for (auto const& vertex : findVertex->second)
     {
         cout << vertex << '\n';
     }
 }
```

If you don't have access to C++11 you can do the same idea manually

```
 if(findVertex != vertexMap.end())
 {
     cout << "\nRecord found: ";
     cout << findVertex->first << '\n';
     for (vector<Vertex>::const_iterator itVertex = findVertex->second.cbegin();
          itVertex != findVertex->second.cend();
          ++itVertex)
     {
         Vertex const& vertex = *itVertex;
         cout << vertex << '\n';
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't have access to C++11 and used the manual version. However, I was presented with this error:                              

`error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<Vertex>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Vertex*, std::vector<Vertex> >}' and 'std::vector<Vertex>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Vertex*, std::vector<Vertex> >}')|`

Comment: @CollinOladimeji Try the edited code now. I changed to `::const_iterator` and use `cbegin()` and `cend()`.

Comment: @Collin Oladimeji  See my answer.:)

Comment: @Cyber Apparently, `error: 'const class std::vector<Vertex>' has no member named 'cbegin'|`. Could I be missing an include?